# Find an orthogonal matrix that transfers one plane to another

Tags: analytic-geometry, orthogonal-matrices

I need to find an orthogonal matrix that transfers the plane $\pi_1=\Bigg\{\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\\z\end{pmatrix}\Bigg|3x+4y+5z=0\Bigg\}$ to the plane
$\pi=\Bigg\{\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\\z\end{pmatrix}\Bigg|5x+5y=0\Bigg\}$.
At first I thought that I maybe need to find two lines from $\pi_1$, then I'll complete a basis by adding one more independent vector, then I'll do $gram-shmidt$, and then Ill do the same with the other plane. And the answer will be the second matrix times the transpose of the first matrix. The problem is that I don't know if it is true, or how to find two lines from $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$.

Comment: Your method is correct (and to find a line in $\pi_1$, simply add another equation, i.e. for instance either $z=0,$ or $y=0$). But a simpler one is to look for an orthogonal matrix which sends $\pi_1^\perp$ to $\pi_2^\perp,$ i.e. sends the vector $\begin{pmatrix} 3\\ 4\\5\end{pmatrix}$ to the vector (of same norm) $\begin{pmatrix} 5\\ 5\\0\end{pmatrix}$ or its opposite.

Comment: @AnneBauval Still can't understand how to find 2 vector lines in $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$. let's say about $\pi_1$: Can I just randomly choose x, and y, and then the coordinate for z will be whatever ill get after putting x and y in the plane? and when I complete it to a basis, the vector I'm adding should also be in the plane, or can I just randomly pick it, for example $\begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$? Thanks!

Comment: Yes your idea is better than mine. Choose $x,y$ and plug them into the equation to get $z.$ Do this twice, independently (since you want 2 vectors in $\pi_1$): e.g. $(x,y)=(1,0)$ and $(x,y)=(0,1).$ Your third basis vector will necessarily be outside the plane. You can choose it at random.

Comment: Thank you! @AnneBauval

Comment: But my method (in my first comment, and detailed below by @JohnDoe ) is quicker. (I did not read completely John's answer yet. If I find sth shorter I'll edit mine.)

Comment: @AnneBauval Hey, I'm kinda new to this platform, can you maybe tell me how can I ask questions diferently so that people will upvote them, so I could get reputation? I'm trying so hard to make the questions as clear as I can, but without any luck. Thank you!

Comment: Making the question clear is necessary but not sufficient. See [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959), especially [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted in my first comment above, your method is correct but a simpler one is to find some orthogonal matrix $R$ sending $u$ to $v$, where
$$x:=\begin{pmatrix} 3\\ 4\\5\end{pmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad y:=\begin{pmatrix} 5\\ 5\\0\end{pmatrix}.$$
A simple $R$ for this is the [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(mathematics)#Reflection_through_a_hyperplane_in_n_dimensions) in the plane orthogonal to
$$z:=y-x=\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\-5\end{pmatrix}:$$
$$R:=I_3-\frac2{z^T\,z}z\,z^T=\frac1{15}\begin{pmatrix}11&-2&10\\-2&14&5\\10&5&-10\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: I understood your method, and it is very interesting. Unfortunately, my professor thought us a different way of solving this. We proved in the lectures that the orthogonal matrix that transfers the plane $\pi_1$ to $\pi_2$ is the same matrix that transfers the norm vector of $\pi_1$ to the norm vector of $\pi_2$. And to solve this we used the gram-Schmidt method. On Monday, I'll ask her about using the reflection matrix. Thank you!

Comment: Even when you choose $y=$ one of the two (opposite) normal vectors of $\pi_2$ having the same norm ($\ne0$ but not necessarily $=1$) as your given normal vector $x$ of $\pi_1,$ there are plenty of orthogonal matrices sending $x$ to $y$ (my $R$ is one of them). Up to here, my method is not different from what you proved in the lectures. What you want to add (Gram-Schmidt) to our common method is much more time consuming that calculating the reflection matrix.

Comment: Yes! I agree with you. The problem is that we didn't do too many questions about reflection matrices. Again, Ill ask my professor what she thinks about the method, and which one in hers opinion is better to use, and why. Thansk again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guideline without doing the calculations.

Let $x = (3,4,5)^t$ and $y=(5,5,0)^t$.  You want an orthogonal matrix that maps $x$ to $y$.  Note that both have Euclidean norm $5\sqrt{2}$.  Their inner products is $35$, so if $\theta\in [0,\pi]$ is the angle between them then $\cos(\theta) = 35/50 = 0.7$ so you know they're not co-linear.  You also know $\sin(\theta) = \sqrt{1-(7/10)^2} = \sqrt{51}/10$.

Now let $u = x/(5\sqrt{2})$, $w = (x\times y)/(50\sin(\theta))$ and $v=w\times u$ where $\times$ is the cross product.  Then $(u, v, w)$ is a right-handed orthonormal basis. In this basis, $y/(5\sqrt{2}) = \cos(\theta) u + \sin(\theta) v$.  Let $A$ be the orthogonal matrix with columns $(u, v, w)$.  You can get an orthogonal matrix rotating $x$ to $y$ by
$$A\pmatrix{
\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)&0\\
\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)&0\\
0&0&1
}A^t$$